# Summing specific elements in nested dict

Tags: python, function, dictionary, sum

I have got 3 different bags that I represent using a nested dictionary. Their keys are 'bag1', 'bag2' and 'bag3' and, in turn, they contain different coloured balls of different quantities, each colour category also represented by a dictionary. How do end up with a dictionary that simply adds all the respective colours in each bag? For example, `dict1 = {'bag1': { 'red' : 2, 'blue' : 5, 'green' : 7}, 'bag2' : { 'red' : 3, 'blue': 4, 'green': 8}}`. Now, I want to end up with another, final dictionary of the form: `dict2 = { 'red' : 5, 'blue': 9, 'green': 15}`. Could someone please provide me with a function to do this?

Comment: Please provide some code that you have tried and mention the problems you have faced.

Comment: Hey! you're new to stackoverflow I am assuming, contributors can't just provide the complete code right away. You have to first tell us the techniques or ways you've tried and difficulties faced, then we'll help you to solve them or provide with a new/effecient solution. But first try to solve it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

First you want to create result dictionary:

```
dict2 = {}
for key in dict1['bag1'].keys():
    dict2[key] = 0
```

then fill it

```
for bag in dict1.values():
    for key, value in bag.items():
        dict2[key] += value
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) from [collections](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) module:

```
from collections import Counter
dict1 = {'bag1': {'red': 2, 'blue': 5, 'green': 7}, 'bag2': {'red': 3, 'blue': 4, 'green': 8}}

counter = sum(map(Counter, dict1.values()), Counter())
print dict(counter)
```

**Output**

```
{'blue': 9, 'green': 15, 'red': 5}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below recursive function `get_value` will find the value of keys from JSON.

```
import json

def get_value(key, mydict):
    if key in mydict:
        return mydict[key]

    if type(mydict) is dict:
        for i in mydict:
            if type(i) is dict:
                return get_value(key, i)
    return 0

def get_sum(dict1, dict2):
    red, blue, green = 0, 0, 0
    red = get_value('red', dict1) + get_value('red', dict2)
    blue = get_value('blue', dict1) + get_value('blue', dict2)
    green = get_value('green', dict1) + get_value('green', dict2)
    return {
        'red':red,
        'blue': blue,
        'green':green
    }

if __name__=="__main__":
    dict1 = {'bag1': { 'red' : 2, 'blue' : 5, 'green' : 7}, 'bag2' : { 'red' : 3, 'blue': 4, 'green': 8}}
    dict2 = { 'red' : 5, 'blue': 9, 'green': 15}
    final_sum = get_sum(dict1, dict2)
    print(final_sum)
```

output: `{'red': 5, 'blue': 9, 'green': 15}`

Answer (score 0):

Using `list comprehensions` to solve this -

```
a=[ d.items() for d in list(dict1.values())]
my_tuples=[item for sublist in a for item in sublist]
my_set = {x[0] for x in my_tuples}
my_sums = dict([(i,sum(x[1] for x in my_tuples if x[0] == i)) for i in my_set])
print(my_sums)
    {'green': 15, 'red': 5, 'blue': 9}
```

[image: Screenshot of the output]

Comment: str object is not callable in line 4.

Comment: I have tested it, it's working. My python version is `3.6.2`.